# cron job not working on macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, cron

I've created a bash script that backups my files on a NAS.
When I run this file manually it works fine.

But want to run this backup every 2 weeks so I created a cronjob

> => crontab -l
>
> 0 22 1,15 * * /Users/ralphschipper/Documents/shFiles/rsbackup.sh

so I checked this at this site:
[crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#30_23_1,15_*_*)

it's now august 16th so it should run yesterday at 10pm right?

this is the code in rsbackup.sh:

```
caffeinate -ims rsync --log-file="/Users/ralphschipper/Documents/Logs/rsync"`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`.log -av /Volumes/Ext\ 1TB/Google\ Drive/ /Volumes/USB_Storage/Backups/Google\ Drive/
#caffeinate -ims rsync --log-file="/Users/ralphschipper/Documents/Logs/rsync"`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`.log -av /Users/ralphschipper/Documents/test_a/ /Users/ralphschipper/Documents/test_b/
cat "/Users/ralphschipper/Documents/Logs/rsync"`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`.log | mail -s "Backuplog" mymail@gmail.com
```

the hashtag at line 2 is for testing

do I miss something here?

Comment: The most likely thing is that your script (`rsbackup.sh`) uses some command that is not in your PATH when run under `cron`. Either show the code for the script, or check that all commands in there are simple commands in `/usr/bin` or `/bin`.

Comment: @Mark Setchell: thanks for your time Mark, I added the contents of the backupscript in my message

Comment: Try running `type caffeinate` in Terminal to get its full path, then use the full path in your script, likewise for `rsync` and `mail`

Comment: Yes! that fixed it: now I use the full path to mail and caffeinate. Thanks Mark